# Installing kbmWM with a newer Indy

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

We have some legacy software programmed in Delphi 2007. I had to upgrade Indy to something quite new from their source snapshot to be able to support TLS v1.2 in my application.

Old Indy was removed and new packages compiled and installed. Note that Indy changed also naming of the packages, currently they are called IndyCore110.bpl etc - with 110 suffix for D2007. Which probably doesn't even matter, since the packages are in any case newly build and the library itself is modified slightly.

Of course, the compiled packages and units from kbmMW CodeGear edition which we used in other parts of the system (and which need to be in the same Delphi environment on the same build machine) are not compatible with the new Indy neither by naming nor by whatever stands for version there, I can't re-install the kbmWM's packages.

If I understand it right, I need to obtain sources for kbmWM in order to be able to re-build and re-install it (while, possibly, fixing some compatibility issues where it comes in contact with new Indy). (Please correct me if this is wrong).

What I don't know is - which edition of kbmWM do I even need, what is the difference between Professional and Enterprise - are they different by component structure or only by licensing/support features? The CodeGear edition - which edition with sources does it correspond to - Professional or Enterprise?

I've attempted to compose a list of components and classes which are definitely explicitly used in our source, maybe this could help in answering the question. Here it is:

```
TkbmMWClientQuery
TkbmMWClientStoredProc
TkbmMWClientConnectionPool
TkbmMWBinaryStreamFormat
TkbmMWTCPIPIndyClientTransport
TkbmMWPooledSession
TkbmMWSimpleClient


TkbmMWServer
TkbmMWTCPIPIndyServerTransport
TkbmMWPooledSession
TkbmMWDBXConnectionPool
TkbmMWMSSQLMetaData
TkbmMWADOXConnectionPool
TkbmMWCustomConnection

TkbmMWClientIdentity
TkbmMWAccessPermissions
TkbmMWCustomServiceForm
TkbmMWCustomService
TkbmMWBinaryStreamFormat
TkbmMemTable
TkbmMWBinaryStreamFormat
```

I hope somebody can either consult me on what edition I might be able to use or advise me on installing the precompiled CodeGear edition together with the updated Indy. The Indy version is 10.0.52 downloaded from here: http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/Files/Indy10.DE.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a question for C4D support... we can guess that you need at least the edition that you are currently using.  If you are using the free CodeGear edition, then it stands to reason that the featureset of any of the paid versions will be a superset of that.

Comment: Why are you asking us rather than asking Kim directly?

Comment: Well, if I knew how to get to Kim directly, maybe I would, but then again - is it such a narrowly specific issue that nobody could benefit from having the answer in the public forum?

Comment: I just think that you'll get the best answer from Kim and it probably is a bit on the narrow side. I'm sure he's easy to contact. Look on the c4d site.

Comment: It sounds like you are using an old version of kbmWM that is compatible with Indy 9, not Indy 10.  And FYI, the version of Indy 10 you downloaded (10.0.52) is **VERY OLD** (the download page you used even says so). The current version is 10.6.2 (SVN rev 5343 at the time of this writing).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think he's aware - I infer that he intentionally got the oldest version of Indy that supported TLS v1.2 in the hopes that, by virtue of its age, it would still be compatible with his old version of kbmWM.

Comment: Hm, believe it or not I managed to glide by the fact that this was an old version of Indy. Yes, it worked for the TLS purpose, but I should definitely try also the latest. Let's see maybe it even helps with kbmWM compatibility.
I did get in touch with C4D's support with the similar questions, about a week ago. Since I have to move on with the task, I decided to additionally ask here in hope somebody would know. Sorry if it's outside of anybody's field of interest.

Comment: Just to keep the record accurate, I have now installed the latest and greatest from the top of the SVN tree. Indy is fine, but of course it helped nothing with reinstalling the kbmMW CG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, for record keeping.

1. CodeGear edition is, in fact a subset of them all, quite close, but not quite as big as Professional. That was actually visible in the Features section of the website.
2. We did purchase a Professional license and in the end I was able to find a combination of versions of MW and MemTable that compiled on D2007
3. It was also possible to hack it a little bit in the part of interface with Indy to accomodate for the changes in the newest packages. I won't go into details here, this remains yet to be tested, for now I just know that it all builds together and projects open and compile.